# Using preg_match to match this specific pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a preg_match matching for specific patterns, but it's just not matching the pattern I'm trying to match. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

$string = "tell me about cats";
preg_match("~\b(?:tell me about|you know(?: of| about)?|what do you think(?: of| about)?|(?:what|who) is|(?:whats|whos)) ((?:[a-z]+ ){1,2})$~", $string, $match);
print_r($match);

?>
```

**Expected Result:**

array(0 => tell me about 1 => cats)

**Actual Result:**

array()

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cN8yO2/1 On the right hand side are explanations of what everything means.

Comment: Useful tool  : [http://regexr.com/](http://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having an extra space in *(but there are no spaces after `cat` making the entire regex to fail)*

```
((?:[a-z]+ ){1,2})
          ^^
          ||
         here
```

also, you don't have capturing group for first part *(due to `(?:..)`)*. Make a capturing group and make the spaces optional using `?` *(if you want to capture at most two words)*

```
\b(tell me about|you know(?: of| about)?|what do you think(?: of| about)?|(?:what|who) is|(?:whats|whos)) ((?:[a-z]+){1,2} ?)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yM3sU2/2)**

*PHP Code*

```
$string = "tell me about cats";
preg_match("~\b(tell me about|you know(?: of| about)?|what do you think(?: of| about)?|(?:what|who) is|(?:whats|whos)) ((?:[a-z]+ ?){1,2})$~", $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**NOTE** :- `$match[1]` and `$match[2]` will contain your result. `$match[0]` is reserved for entire match found by the regex in the string.

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/v36Ual)**

Comment: The reason I put {1,2} at the end was because I wanted to match one OR two words, but at least one. Removing the space makes it so that it only matches ONE word.